# Area under ROC for the multiclass problem in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, roc, multiclass-classification, auc

I working on Sentiment Analysis program. But I manage to include "**neutral**" in the category beside "**positive**" and "**negative**". And it makes the category multiclass.

So can I make `roc_auc_score` work in multiclass ? Or there is another way to do the measurement performance beside using `roc_auc_score`?

My `roc_auc_score` implementation:

```
print(roc_auc_score(y_test, clf.predict_proba(X_test)[:,1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can.

See [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html):

> Note: this implementation can be used with binary, multiclass and multilabel classification, but some restrictions apply (see Parameters).

and [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html#area-under-roc-for-the-multiclass-problem):

> The `sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score` function can be used for multi-class classification.

As an example, let's use iris dataset:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

iris = load_iris()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(iris.data,
                                                    iris.target,
                                                    stratify = iris.target,
                                                    random_state = 42)


model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
print('roc auc score: {:.4f}'.format(roc_auc_score(y_test, model.predict_proba(X_test), multi_class='ovo')))
```

and you get:

> roc auc score: 0.9808

Comment: It generates this error : 

"roc_auc_score() got an unexpected keyword argument 'multi_class'"

There is no "multi_class" parameter on my roc_auc_score.. Why did it happen ??

Comment: What version do you have?